# Two Responsive Crossfading Images side by side

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations

I am creating a new website and I have created two crossfading images side by side in different div bodies. Those crossfading images are working perfectly on full screen but when I reduce my browser's screen the images stay in the same pixels as they originally are. I want those images to shrink and fit on the screen according to the device like responsive websites I want to make those crossfading images responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.le,
.ri {
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
}

.le {
  float: left;
  align-self: center;
}

.ri {
  float: right;
  align-self: center;
}

</style><style type="text/css">.responsive {
  width: 761px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

</style><style type="text/css">.responsive1 {
  width: 761px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

</style><style type="text/css">#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.responsive1:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

</style><style type="text/css">#cf1 img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf1 img.responsive2:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="cf" class="le">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="responsive" src=".jpg">
      <img class="responsive1" src=".jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="cf1" class="ri">
    <img class="responsive" src=".jpg" />
    <img class="responsive2" src=".jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options for making images responsive.

A simple solution is to make the images 100% width. The images will then grow and shrink.

Another solution is to use a [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for the images and configure the shrink and grow behavior with flex box.

You could also use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and only set the width to 100% before or after a specific device width.

Comment: I solved it. I put all the images class names on a single style tag and I set the Max-Width to 50%. Thanks for the Help.